# SQL Comment Grouping

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table in MySQL

Table 1: List of ID's

--Just a single column list of ID's

Table 2: Groups

--Group Titles

--Members **

Now the member field is basically a comments field where all the ID's that are part of that group are listed. So for instance one whole field of members looks like this:

```
"ID003|ID004|ID005|ID006|ID007|ID008|... Etc."
```

There they can be up to 500+ listed in the field.

What I would like to do is to run a query and find out which ID's appear in only three or less groups.

I've been taking cracks at it, but honestly I'm totally lost. Any ideas?

Comment: What @Mihai is sarcastically pointing out is that you have a fundamental DB design issue. You really need to normalized that data.  Are you open for suggestions on changing your DB schema, because without that, I would recommend just trying to solve this problem in your programming language of choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit; I misunderstood the question the first time, so I'm changing my answer.

```
SELECT l.id
FROM List_of_ids AS l
JOIN Groups AS g ON CONCAT('|', g.members, '|') LIKE CONCAT('%|', l.id, '|%')
GROUP BY l.id
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
```

This is bound to perform very poorly, because it forces a table-scan of both tables. If you have 500 id's and 500 groups, it must run 250000 comparisons.

You should really consider if storing a symbol-separated list is the right way to do this. See my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

The proper way to design such a relationship is to create a third table that maps id's to groups:

```
CREATE TABLE GroupsIds (
  memberid INT,
  groupid INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (memberid, groupid)
);
```

With this table, it would be much more efficient by using an index for the join:

```
SELECT l.id
FROM List_of_ids AS l
JOIN GroupsIds AS gi ON gi.memberid = l.id
GROUP BY l.id
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how that helps on getting which ID's appear in only three or less groups?

Comment: @FilipeSilva The difference in length between the string with separators adn the string without shows the number of ids.Separators=number of groups,separator being 1 character.

Comment: this query solves a little bit different problem, it shows groups with 3 or less members, but OP needs to find members with 3 or less groups

Comment: @Mihai I see. That is indeed a clever trick to get how many ids are in there, but i'm not sure that addresses OP's problem.

Comment: @FilipeSilva, you're right, I misunderstood the OP's question, so I have written a new answer.

Comment: @BillKarwin. Yes. i saw that. Looks more on point now. But i still liked the trick you had before :)

Comment: Excellent Mr. Karwin. Worked just as labeled, thank you!

Sadly the DB design is out of my hands, all I can do is make suggests to improve it and work with what I have.

Comment: That's a common situation, alas.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from
(
    select ID,
    (
        select count(*)
        From Groups
        where LOCATE(concat('ID', a.id, '|'), concat(Members, '|'))>0
    ) as groupcount
    from ListIDTable as a
) as q
where groupcount <= 3
```